# error while send message using azure servicebus topic's shared access connection string with "WindowsAzure.ServiceBus" nuget

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-servicebus-topics

I am using `WindowsAzure.ServiceBus` nuget package and try to send message on topic using topic level shared access policy(send only) but it will give me below error.

```
 40103: Invalid authorization token signature, Resource:sb://testsb.servicebus.windows.net/testtopicname.
```

But when I tried to use `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus` nuget same connection string working fine and it's also working fine if I used service bus level shared access policy connection string(send only).

How I can send topic message using topic level shared access policy using `WindowsAzure.ServiceBus` nuget package.

Comment: That's off as both clients should behave the same. Suggest to raise an issue [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/issues).

Comment: Thanks @SeanFeldman, I will create an issue.
Btw issue solved by using only one parameter inTopicClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionStringWithTopicName)
And remove second parameter topicNameOfServiceBus.

Comment: Looks like you're using the old client. Since topic name is required, are you providing via property once client is created? Feels like the overload method with two parameters does something wrong.  For issue.

Comment: Yes, New client require .netStandardFramework but my application is in .net framework 4.6+.

Comment: The new client is .NET Standard. It means it will work with .NET Core _and_ Full Framework.